# Filtering an NSSet based on equality with different objects in another NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsset

I have 2 types of objects.

Class A is a subclass of NSManagedObject.
Class B is a subclass of NSObject.

S(A) is an NSSet containing objects of class A.
S(B) is an NSSet containing objects of class B.

I have a custom comparator on class A to figure out if it matches an object of class B.

I need to filter S(A) such that after the filtering operation, only those objects remain in S(A) which have a valid match in S(B).

My current naive solution iterates over S(A), and for each object iterates over S(B) which has a time complexity of O(mn) (m is the size of S(A), n is the size of S(B)).

The biggest constraint here is that A is a subclass of NSManagedObject and therefore I cannot override the -isEqual: and -hash methods to take advantage of the -intersectSet: method on NSMutableSet.

I'm looking for a solution better than O(mn). Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there some way to order the two sets so that finding a match becomes quicker than O(n)?

Comment: What constitutes equivalence? A single key/value pair? Can you leverage that? Being a set you can remove matched items as you know they can't be seen again.

Comment: Equivalence is based on 1 string comparison and 1 integer equality.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an O(m+n) solution to this problem by using the following method.

The custom comparator between class A and B relied on a string comparison and an integer equality.

Lets say these properties are

- NSString *s
- NSInteger i

I created an NSMutableDictionary with objects of class A and key as a hash of the string s and integer i. This process is O(m) as it involves iteration over S(A).

After this I iterate over S(B), and create the same hash using the string s and integer i from objects of class B, and look up objects in the above create NSMutableDictionary. If a match exists, I perform desired operation. This process is O(n).

While this solution takes a larger space, but is an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: Or you can apply the similar technique from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20624429/compare-2-nsarrays-in-objective-c/20624929#20624929

Comment: @user523234 That won't work because in my case I can't use -containsObject or anything else that relies on the -isEqual properties. I mentioned that in the problem statement mentioned above.

Comment: Right, use your "custom comparator" ....  And return YES or NO appropriately in the block.

Comment: Never mind my suggestion.  Upon re-read your question, it probably not much better.

Comment: Yeah, your suggestion would lead to a similar O(mn) solution which would be the same as a naive solution.